# Does tornado's SimpleAsyncHTTPClient handle multiple A records with retries?

Tags: dns, tornado

We are setting up multiple proxies (each of which will be an A record). We want to ensure that if one of these proxies fails that the hostname is still alive.

Answer (score 0):

[No](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/simple_httpclient.py#L172).

But curl_httpclient should (cURL does).